# matrix flow: to the right instead of downwards?

Tags: r

I'm not sure what you call this, but the default 'flow' of matrices is downwards (as seen below)

```
matrix(1,7,5)*(1:7)
1    1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3    3
4    4    4    4    4
5    5    5    5    5
6    6    6    6    6
7    7    7    7    7
```

What if your intention is to multiply the vector to the right instead of downwards? Is there a better way to write the command below? Is there a toggle for column instead of row (same for `replicate(7,1:7)` it assumes downwards flow (paste row vectors downwards instead of column vectors to the right); is transpose the solution?)

```
t(t(matrix(1,7,5))*(1:5))
1    2    3    4    5
1    2    3    4    5
1    2    3    4    5
1    2    3    4    5
1    2    3    4    5
1    2    3    4    5
1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: To post code, just add four spaces before each line. Or select your code and press the `{}` button. There *used to be* a quick formatting reference on the right of the question asking page. There is also the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page

Comment: What you're calling "flow" is often referred to as [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_major#Column-major_order) or [row-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_major#Row-major_order) ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this a lot after defining the matrix you can always make an operator yourself:

```
'%mat%'<- function(x,y)t(t(x)*y)
matrix(1,7,5)%mat%1:5
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5
[7,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

But I think it easier to just transpose twice as you said in the question:

```
t(t(matrix(1,7,5))*1:5)
```

Or of course opt to transpose the matrix once in the beginning, do everything you need to do with it and then transpose it back.

As far as I know there is no way to change the default behaviour of *, nor would you probably want too,

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is simply a vector with a dim attribute. The elements of the matrix are stored in the vector in column-major order and there is no way to change this.  `*` is an element-by-element operator that recycles its arguments as necessary.  You can see the recycling rule at work via:

```
> x <- matrix(1,7,5)
> x*1:5
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    2    4
[2,]    2    4    1    3    5
[3,]    3    5    2    4    1
[4,]    4    1    3    5    2
[5,]    5    2    4    1    3
[6,]    1    3    5    2    4
[7,]    2    4    1    3    5
```

You can see the multiplication is taking place by column and the vector (`1:5`) is being recycled to be the same length as the matrix.  Rather than transposing, you could use the `matrix` function to re-size your matrix by row.

```
> matrix(x*1:5,nrow(x),ncol(x),byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5
[7,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

I'm not sure that's the *most efficient* solution, but it's the best I can think of at the moment and it's slightly faster than using `t` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
> matrix(rep(1:7,5), nrow=7, ncol=5)
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5
[6,]    6    6    6    6    6
[7,]    7    7    7    7    7

> matrix(rep(1:7,5), nrow=5, ncol=7, byrow=TRUE)
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
```

Comment: i want to multiply a nxm matrix with a vector of length m. when i multiply it using the <code>matrix*vector</code> it multiplies downwards causing a mismatch in numbers (n vs m) which is not my intention. i want it to multiply rightwards. Joshua pointed out that this property is called column-major. Is there a way to change this property or is my solution of using transpose sufficient? (im just concerned that the code is not optimized since it transposes twice just to get back to the original orientation)... it might matter if the simulations or matrices are large...